# Multiple tabs selected after certain touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set up some code to switch between different tabs, and it works pretty well for the most part, except there are some edge cases on mobile that's been giving me trouble.

If I tap one of the buttons normally (i.e. positions of `touchstart` and `touchend` are both on the same button), it behaves normally; the button tapped becomes active and the appropriate view becomes visible. It works well on desktop, too. I even added some `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to make a tab (only one tab) active on hover.

However, problems arise when the positions of the `touchstart` and `touchend` events vary. If, for example, with the "Contact" tab selected, I tap "Updates", move my finger over to "Bio", and release, "Bio" and "Contact" both appear to be selected, as shown below.

[image: multiple tabs selected]

The expected behavior in this situation would be for "Bio" to be active with the "Bio" view shown. There are at least two other edge cases, such as swiping onto or off of a button, that do not work as expected with my current configuration. Any help that doesn't disrupt the cases that work is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // show appropriate view based on document hash
    if (document.location.hash) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }, 1);
    }

    if (document.location.hash === '' ||
        document.location.hash === '#' ||
        document.location.hash === '#bio') {
        $('#bio').show();
        $('#tabs-bio').addClass('active');
    } else if (document.location.hash === '#updates') {
        $('#updates').show();
        $('#tabs-updates').addClass('active');
    } else if (document.location.hash === '#contact') {
        $('#contact').show();
        $('#tabs-contact').addClass('active');
    }

    // define tabs behavior
    var $activeTab = $('.active');
    var $tabsChildren = $('.tabs > li');
    $tabsChildren.on('click touchstart', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        $tabsChildren.each(function () {
            $($(this).data('href')).hide();
            if (event.type === 'click') {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });

        $activeTab = $(this);
        $($(this).data('href')).show();
    });

    $('.tabs').mouseenter(function () {
        $activeTab.removeClass('active');
    });
    $('.tabs').mouseleave(function () {
        $activeTab.addClass('active');
    });
    $(window).on('touchstart', function () {
        $activeTab.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.tabs {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.25rem;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.tabs-3 {
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
  grid-template-columns: calc((100% - 0.5rem)/3) calc((100% - 0.5rem)/3) calc((100% - 0.5rem)/3);
}

.tabs li {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ced4da;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs .active {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
}

#page > div {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="tabs tabs-3">
    <li class="center" id="tabs-bio" data-href="#bio">Bio</li>
    <li class="center" id="tabs-updates" data-href="#updates">Updates</li>
    <li class="center" id="tabs-contact" data-href="#contact">Contact</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="bio">
      <h3>Bio</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="updates">
      <h3>Updates</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      <h3>Contact</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the interaction you're going for on desktop and probably trying to mimic that on mobile.

> On Desktop you have an active state (ie Bio) but on hover over the
>   tabs you ignore the active tab and have hover effect, if the user
>   selects no option and hovers out the active tab resumes its active
>   style, but if the user selects a new tab the new one assumes the
>   active state.

Here's that changes I would propose:

On `touchstart` don't actually change the tab as the user might not end up actually want to select the tab - either sliding away or they were actually just trying to scroll, your function re-written:

```
$tabsChildren.on('click touchstart', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    $tabsChildren.removeClass('active');

    if (event.type === 'click') {
      $tabsChildren
        .removeClass('active')
        .each(function () {
          $($(this).data('href')).hide();
        });

      $activeTab = $(this);
      $($(this).data('href')).show();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Notice I'm still adding the `active` class just to show the "hover" style.

Now use `touchend` to figure out if the user actually intended to select the tab:

```
$tabsChildren.on('touchend', function (event) {
  var changes = event.changedTouches[0];
  var $endEl = $(document.elementFromPoint(changes.pageX, changes.pageY));

  if ($endEl.parent('.tabs').length) {
    $tabsChildren
      .removeClass('active')
      .each(function () {
        $($(this).data('href')).hide();
      });

    $activeTab = $endEl;
    $endEl.addClass('active');
    $($endEl.data('href')).show();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

What we want to do is not use `$(this)` (where the user started the touch) but figure out what the element is at the end. If the user actually ended at a different tab - select that. If the user ended up not on a tab at all, don't do anything and let this catch it:

```
$(window).on('touchend', function () {
  $tabsChildren.removeClass('active');
  $activeTab.addClass('active');
});
```

Which we reset the tab back to the original active one.

Here's the code in action https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBzeEP?editors=0010 and also preview.

[image]